# ansible docker-compose module, different result from ansible than over ssh on the host

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, ansible, ansible-role

I have a task in my Ansible Bitbucket role that simply starts two docker-compose.yml files.
When executing this from Ansible it fails but when I execute the same command over ssh on the actual server it works just fine. I am currently executing my playbook as root, and when i manually execute docker-compose -f <path> up -d I am also root.

```
- name: Create and start services
    - name: docker compose up
      docker_compose:
        project_src: "{{ bitbucket__install_path }}"
        files: "{{ bitbucket__compose_files }}"
        state: present
      register: output
```

Ansible command:

> ansible-playbook -i inventory/staging playbooks/bitbucket-server.yml -vvvv -kKu root --ask-vault-pass --start-at-task "Setup bitbucket"

Ansible sucessfully starts 2 out of 3 containers but the third crashes with the error:

> Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
> container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec:
> "/my_entrypoint.sh": permission denied: unknown Error: failed to start
> containers: nginx_bitbucket_1

My question is, why do Ansible receive an error when executing the above task while executing "docker-compose -f <path> up -d over ssh works just fine? What is the difference between the two cases?

Comment: you hadn't provided enough info to answer. My wild guess may be that you run it from different user compare to your ssh session.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this problem.
The problem is that the files field did not operate as I expected.

> List of Compose file names relative to project_src. Overrides
> docker-compose.yml or docker-compose.yaml. Files are loaded and merged
> in the order given.

I thought the files parameter would execute docker-compose -f <path> up on each list element defined in the parameter.

I changed my code to use a loop rather than the files parameter

```
 - name: Create and start services                                                                                                                  
  docker_compose:
    project_src: "{{ bitbucket__install_path }}/{{ item }}"                                                                                        
    state: present                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  loop:
    - nginx
    - bitbucket
```

It finished sucessfully